# Let $G$ be the group defined by $G = \{A \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\Bbb R) \mid A^tA=r^2I, r>0,\det A >0\}.$ Find the Lie algebra of $G$.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $G$ be the group defined by $$G = \{A \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\Bbb R) \mid A^tA=r^2I, r>0,\det A >0\}.$$ Find the Lie algebra of $G$.

I've managed to figure out that the elements of $G$ take the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}, \ a^2+b^2=r^2$$ by some elementary trigonometry.

I'm having difficulties figuring out what $T_IG$ should be. If $X \in T_IG$ and $c:(a,b) \to G$ is a smooth path with $c(0)=I$ and $c'(0)=X$, then $c(t) \in G$ and we have two conditions $$c(t)^Tc(t)=r^2I, \ \det c(t)>0.$$

From $\det c(t) >0$ we get that $$\operatorname{tr} X >0$$ so the elements of the diagonal on $X$ should have a positive sum. Can I apply the product rule to $c(t)^Tc(t)=r^2I$? That is $$(c(t)^T)'c(t)+c(t)^Tc'(t)=0?$$ This would give that $X^T+X=0$ i.e. that $X$ is skew-symmetric?

Comment: I'm trying to do this exactly by figuring out how $X$ should behave. It would seem to be that at least $-a_{12} = a_{21}$ if $a_{ij}$'s are the entries of the matrix, but I don't think that $\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&-a_{12}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ fully characterizes $X$ yet since $a_{11} + a_{22}$ could be zero or negative. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by equations? For the entries of a matrix in $G$ we have $a_{11} - a_{22} = 0$ and $a_{12} + a_{21} = 0$. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: Note that $G$ contains rescaled orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This is a very precise estimate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the definition of $G$: $r$ is not a fixed value, but a free parameter (indeed, if $r$ was fixed, it could only be $1$ since $I_2$ must belong to $G$, as a subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$).
From your computation, it appears that
$$
G = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} r\cos \theta & -r\sin \theta \\ r\sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{pmatrix} \mid r \neq 0, \theta \in \Bbb R \right\}.
$$
The Lie algebra of $G$ is given by the tangent space at $I_2$.
Let $$c(t) = \begin{pmatrix} r(t)\cos \theta(t) & -r(t)\sin \theta(t) \\ r(t)\sin \theta(t) & r(t) \cos \theta(t) \end{pmatrix} = r(t)\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta(t) & -\sin \theta(t) \\ \sin \theta(t) &  \cos \theta(t) \end{pmatrix}$$
be a curve with $c(0) = I_2$, *i.e* $r(0) = 1$ and $\theta(0) = 0 \pmod 2\pi$.
Leibniz rule yields
$$
c'(t) = r'(t)\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta(t) & -\sin \theta(t) \\ \sin \theta(t) &  \cos \theta(t) \end{pmatrix}
+ r(t) \theta'(t) \begin{pmatrix} -\sin \theta(t) & -\cos \theta(t) \\ \cos \theta(t) &  -\sin \theta(t) \end{pmatrix}
$$
and at $t=0$, this yields
$$
c'(0) = r'(0) I_2 + \theta'(0)\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
One then sees that all these tangent vectors at $I_2$ have the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b &a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$, without any further restriction.

Comment: So $\theta$ is also a function of $t$? @didier

Comment: @NathanielJohonson For a curve $c\colon (a,b) \to G$, of course.